# Cycles Rendering vs Eevee Reflections difference!

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me why there is extra shading popping up in cycles that is not appearing in EEvee? nothing is changed in both. Everything is the same.

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3GYGVzyb

Comment: hello, probably because Cycles is correctly reflecting the environment (here, probably your plane) while Eevee doesn't, Eevee reflects lights but not environment unless you use Light Probe. If you share your file we will be able to check

Comment: Read my answer here, I hope it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: @moonboots https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3GYGVzyb here is the link. sure, let me go through your answer too. thank you!

Comment: You were right :D that was reflection due to my plane!