# Is there something I'm doing wrong with reflections in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I've added screen space reflections and want my renders to look similar to how cycle's reflections appear. I'm not sure if I've added irradiance volume incorrectly but my render doesn't seem to have the same reflection in the glass as cycle's. You can see the joystick in the cycles reflection, but not in eevee.

On cycles you can see more reflections in the back window too.

[image: Cycles]

[image: Eevee]

Comment: take a look here, if your mirror is just a plane, use a Light Probe > Reflection Plane and you won't need to bake: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: @moonboots ahh thank you, I shall give this a try :)