# Why isn't my plane becoming glossy even after making roughness to zero?

Tags: texturing

I am new to Blender and I have added an emission texture to a sphere which is supposed to be a sun

Why isn't my plane becoming glossy even after making roughness to zero?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, if you are using EEVEE render, you need to turn on "Screen space reflections" (Render properties > Screen Space Reflections)

Comment: if Emirs comment doesn't help, please provide blend file

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a proper reflection in Eevee unless you create a *Light Probe > Reflection Cubemap* around your scene (as your object is not flat you can't use a *Reflection Plane*) and then *Bake Indirect Lighting* in the *Render panel > Indirect Lighting* (also see my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee)). But if you animate your sphere the reflection won't be animated. You can fake the reflection with a light though, just put it at the same position as your sun and give it enough *Radius*.