# Renders is Cycles are good but how can I achieve similar results in EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I want to achieve realism close to Cycles but in EEVEE for real-time rendering. The render or model looks good in Cycles but in EEVEE it's abysmal. I don't know what is going wrong. Why does the model look so washed out in EEVEE and how can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Eevee will only reflect correctly if you use Light Probes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Answer (score 4):

The reason that EEVEE provides fast (real-time) rendering is precisely that it doesn't model realism.  You can enable features in EEVEE that will improve its approximation but you will rarely reach Cycles' level of realism at EEVEE's level of performance.

In your example, the problem is, in part, that you need *Screen Space Reflections* (and Refraction) in EEVEE.  You have to enable *Screen Space Reflections* in the properties editor, in the *Render Properties* tab:

[image: Render properties showing Screen Space Reflections enabled]

You also need to edit your materials in the material properties tab and enable *Screen Space Refraction*:

[image: Material setting showing Screen Space Refractions checkbox]

You may also need to adjust the roughness of the material, as well as the lighting, to compensate for EEVEE's behavior.

Answer (score 4):

In Eevee you'll need to use *Light Probes* to have better reflections, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee). In your case, as your objects are flat, use *Reflection Planes* (put them at the same place as your cubes, and just move them a bit):

[image]