# Plane is not reflecting object

Tags: shaders, lighting, reflection

I'm new to blender. I'm trying to reflect an object on a surface.

Following [this youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/1qBOEj7mdiI) I've added a plane with Glossy material and an object on top of it.

[image]

But the object is not reflecting on the plane in the render

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you did not move anything, you need one of two thing. 1 .- Turn on Screen space reflection inside the render settings because you are using EEVEE Render or 2.- Switch to Cycles render engine.

Comment: @Emir Thanks that worked

Comment: if you want a good reflection you'll need a Light Probe > Relfection Plane, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Answer (score 2):

As @Emir pointed out in the comment I turned the `Screen Space Reflections` on render settings

[image]