# How do I make a metal material in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

How can I make a metal material in Eevee without needing to use an HDRI in the whole scene?
Is there a way to simulate the metal material with gradient nodes or other nodes in the shader editor?

I've already searched the internet for tutorials about it, but it seems to always be necessary to have an HDRI in the whole scene.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't use HDRI you need something to reflect, like your objects in your scene, in Eevee your objects won't be correctly reflected unless you use Light Probes, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: in a still image: is there a way to simulate metal materials? for example: with gradients in the proper channels of the material? are there tutorials?

Comment: of course you can simulate metal, in the Principled BSDF you need to put the Metallic value at one, play with the Roughness value, you can also plug a b&w texture into the Roughness. To give a bit of bump, plug a Noise Texture into a Bump node into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF, etc... it all depends on what you want to achieve, maybe show some pictures?

Answer (score 1):

#**Metal Material**

To make a metal material in EEVEE is very simple

1. first make sure your object was assigned to the material
2. go to the shading tab
   [image]
3. see on shading editor, there is a default node
   and see on principled BSDF node
4. edit the metallic, specular, and roughness to value do you want. 
   for example: 
    [image]

> make sure the roughness value is smaller than the specular and
> metallic value

5. check this 
    [image]

- and here is the result 
  [image]

> Without HDRI

#**Animate The Metal With Gradient**

I'll give you a simple step for this

1. search this node (press F3 on Keyboard) and add it
   [image]
2. connect the color ramp to Principled BSDF
   [image]
3. and to animate it, follow this 
   [image]