# Why doesn't my material show up?

Tags: materials

Im new to blender and I can't seem to get the metallic texture to work. If I also change a color of an object it doesn't go to that specific color( darker) [image]

Thank you :)

Comment: in Eevee, by default, you'll only see the reflection of the world and of the lights, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: Have you enabled [X] Screen Space Reflections in the Eevee render settings? It's not enabled by default and only the light and the grey world color but not the floor is mirrored in the metallic sphere.