# Material reflects generic light but not custom emissive material

Tags: shaders, lighting, reflection, emission

I have a wall with a reflective material. If I put a generic light source (point and area) they are both reflected and you can see their form in the reflections, however I have then a custom emissive material (the large pink beam) but the form is not reflected like the other two.

Why doesn't it also reflects it? (and how can I make it do it)

[image]

P.s: Really new to Blender

Comment: Are you using eevee? If so, emissive surfaces are not reflected as they are in Cycles. You must use an _Irradiance Volume_  to make emissions "light things up/cast a glow", and possibly a _reflection plane_ and/or _reflection cubemap_ if you want the shape of the emitter object to be reflected. Lastly, _screen space reflections_ must be enabled.

Comment: maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: Thank you, will check both!