# Light emitting object from behind the camera not reflecting from another object EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, reflection, emission

As title says, I have a big cube serving as a room, image below:
[image]

[image]

There is also a cube with a metallic texture that reflects the lights of the cube, image below:

[image]

But as you can see in this image, the surfaces that should reflect the light coming from behind and above the camera, don't reflect. I imagine there's some culling happening. Is there any way to circumvent this or to force eevee to render these reflections?

I have tried Irradiance Volume + Indirect Lighting Baking.

Cycles does it fine, just doesn't look half as good, and takes a billion years to render.

Comment: Maybe see this answer about Light Probes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: @moonboots My savior, I appreciate it! I tried using reflection planes before, but I was using them wrong, this post is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!