# Is it possible to render out animated textures using Eevee?

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I have an animated environment texture and affects the lighting and reflection of my model. Changes are visible when rendered out using Cycles, but it doesn't work when I try to do the same with Eevee. I'm using Blender 3.1.2 btw. I really need it to be Eevee cause I have tens of thousands of frames to render and it is the only viable option.

Comment: maybe you'll find your answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: Should work with eevee. Can you share material setup?

Comment: @Crantisz it is actually applied to the World Background. Funny thing, it works when you manually slide through the timeline. It's almost as if Eevee reads the Light Cache referencing previous frames or the first frame and that affects the rendering. Cause when it reads the frame in the viewport it actually updates as it is supposed to.