# Reflection problem

Tags: rendering, mirror, reflection, lightprobe

Guys I'm using blender so I want to create a mirror in it. I was turn on the screen space reflection in both render tab and material tab and reflection plane is also fit to plane object and also used both glossy and principled bsdf with roughness 0 and blend mode is also opaque. Every thing is correct but I didn't get the reflection can any one help me with it. And the main thing is at first I'm  success to create a mirror but now it's failing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Try posting screenshots, gifs of your problems or you can [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file.

Comment: maybe this answer will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee