# How to create a mirror which reflects other objects

Tags: edit-mode

I have watched 3 different Youtube videos one using Cycles and Evee and 2 using Evee only.
try as I might and watching and copying every 'move' in each video of which I have tried at least 4 or 5 times I just cannot get5 my 'mirror' to reflect other objects (eg a sphere mesh)  placed in front of my 'mirror'.
I create my mesh (simple cube with dimensions changed to look my a sheet of mirror glass.
Add material with Metallic = 1  and Roughness = 0
I then see reflections of the 'environment'.
I then add the reflection plane and move it just over the 'mirror'
Add a mesh sphere and the mirror I created does not reflect it.
What else needs to be done

Comment: Turn on "Screen Space Reflections" under _Render Properties_. In the case of a reflection plane, you will also need to "bake" the reflections (also under _Render Properties > Indirect lighting_).

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes I already had 'screen space reflections' turned on and 'half res trace' turned off (the video showed that) but forgot to mention that in the question. Strangely when I 'redid' the exercise I now see the reflection correctly (I had tried multiple times before without success) and wonder if it has something to do with the order of applying each step. I have since had contact the author who advised that he too sometimes doesn't get the reflection to work. Also maybe this time I increased the 'scene light strength' (under viewpoint shading scene lights) from 1 to 2. Thanks again.

Comment: does it answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: @moonboots  Thanks for the link. As my object is a mirror I applied Light Probe > Reflection Plane as mentioned in that link but still could not get full reflection.  Many hours later I redid the 'exercise' and this time the (full) reflections worked. Maybe I 'applied' things in a slightly different 'order'. Also I increase the strength of the 'scene lights' (Viewport Shading) from 1 to 2 but when I reset it to 1 the (full) reflection remained so can't see how that caused my initial problem. As the author of the tutorial advised that he has experienced the problem occasionally it is a mystery

Comment: Maybe its just that the positioning of the reflection plane was the cause as I know that one almost needs a 'verier caliper' to position it just right, its positioning seems to have to be within something very small (1mm?). Even holding down the shift key when moving it back and forward is 'touchy'.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file with just the light, the object and the mirror object so that we can test?

Comment: I assume that you mean when there is no full reflection with the reflection plane in place  (if I can now reproduce that)? I will try tomorrow as it is now 10pm.