# Light Reflection Problem in Eevee

Tags: lighting, reflection

I have rendered a scene both in Eevee and Cycles.. Render in Eevee is really bad and not showing any reflections of the lighting..

Settings in Eevee:

- Render Properties Screen Space Reflections on.. Refraction checked.. Base Settings..
- Material Settings Screen Space Refraction on..

Is there a way to get Eevee Reflections to approximate the Cycles Reflections so I don't need to go for the longer rendering time when rendering animations?

[image]

Cycles Result

[image]

Eevee Result

Comment: See my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: Stupid question: screen space reflections and refractions are for glossy reflections on surfaces, mirrors and glass. But what I see in your screenshot looks like a fire illuminating the scene, is this correct? Of course surfaces get illuminated by reflecting light, but therefore light has to hit these surfaces. In _Eevee_, all kinds of material-based lights like emissive meshes, fire materials etc. don't generate light.