# Substance painter textures look different in blender

Tags: texturing, roughness

I imported some textures into blender from substance painter and they look drastically different. I think the main issue I the roughness.

I have all the maps set to non-color and the normal map is an OpenGL map, does anyone know what would be causing this and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**
**Curve Modifier Adjustments**
Cyles:
[image]

Evee:
[image]
Nodes:
[image]

[image]

**Edit:** New object textures (for @vklidu)
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could add a Curve node between the texture and the Principle BSDF to adjust the Roughness

Comment: so what soft is it in the first image? Are you sure that it is not a problem of environment? A metallic material needs an environment to reflect (like an HDRI image)

Comment: As @moonboots said above. Unless you have environment and lights set exactly the same in both programs and it still looks different, then you could have an issue.

Comment: +1 moonboots ... also eevee/cycles?

Comment: @vklidu it is cycles, and i have messed around with different hdris and lighting but the roughness always looks very odd. It isnt smooth like in substance painter, its very harsh instead

Comment: @moonboots I added a curve node and it didnt seem to help, do you have any other suggestions? (I added pictures of the curve node so you can see the results)

Comment: In Eevee, by default, your object won't reflect any other object, only the HDRI image and the lights. But you can create a Light Probe, and also an HDRI if it doesn't already exist. See this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee

Comment: The curve node could help a bit, but you need to add more than one point to the curve. It's a try and test. The curve is manipulating the amount of white, grey and black on your texture, play with that

Comment: OK... Would be more effective if you can share metal object and room object with lights (packed texture)... https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @vklidu i added the file to the post

Comment: Thanks ... first your panel object has no material, secondly - packed is only Roughness texture, but Substance Painter generates for PBR material several textures (Albedo (color), Roughness, Glossiness, Metallness, Normal, Bump, Ambient Occlusion ... or what ever) ... you can setup material with just single one, but if you are looking for the same result you would need them all. At third - The packed texture is for Plane.007 and 017.**

Comment: Import the HDR map you're using in substance painter to blender so you can have a similar lighting. It might still look a bit different tho. If you want to make sure the texture maps are not the problem, open a new substance scene with your model and add the exported textures in your material. If it looks the same as the other scene (the one you were texturing your model in), then it's a lighting problem

Comment: @vklidu sorry for the issue with the packing. I tried applying only the steel roughness material to an object and i brought over all the textures into blender the roughness still looks terrible. I posted new pictures to the post for you to see

Comment: Your images are not helping me. To compare screen of one object and texture of another with different view angles dent make a sense. I suggest to you clean up your Question - add a Cube (on a white Plane), add material to the Cube. Take a shot in Substance, take the same shot (view) in Blender. Pack imported textures into Blender and share those files by editing your Q. To compare reflective material make a sense only if a light condition, environment and view angle matches. ... and probably Alex is right -you deal with differences in environment texture reflected in texture (object).

Answer (score -1):

**Substance Painter**, material *Steel used Scan*, environment *corsica_beach* ...

[image]

... exported textures ...

[image]

... used by Blender ...

[image]
[image]

Note:
I have an access only to Substance Painter 1. By default the app is using environment "panorama.exr", that is not (for some reason) in *resources* folder. So I used "corsica_beach.exr" located inside the app with others ...
**Mac**
Substance\ Painter.app/Contents/Resources/shelf/allegorithmic/environments
**Win**
Substance Painter\resources\shelf\allegorithmic\environments\

Comment: For downvoter: Please, share your thoughts. Would be helpful to comment a reason for your act. So I can improve the answer. Like now I don't have clue what is wrong with my answer for you. Thanks