# Material glass BSDF not applied to mesh

Tags: mesh, glass, emission

I applied a *Glass BSDF* material to a mesh and then added an *Emission* material to a plane to reflect it on that mesh, but it doesn't work as it should.

[image]

and *Emission* material on plane above it:

[image]

This is how it looks in the tutorial video:

[image]

Blender file
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: Eevee is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a glass work in Eevee you need to enable some options, like *Render panel > Screen Space Reflections* and *Refractions*:

[image]

And for the material you need to set the *Settings* to *Alpha Blend* and enable *Screen Space Refraction*:

[image]

That said, you won't have any reflection of an *Emission* material in Eevee, unless you use a *Light Probe*, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee). But you can use a *Light > Area* instead, lights will be reflected.