# How do I remove the camera visibility in eevee but keep the diffuse glossy and other properties intact?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image]

I want to remove this plane from the camera visibility but keep the glossy property it's having on my can, how do I do it so?

Comment: Hello, if you are in Cycles you can go into the Object panel > Visibility > Ray Visibility and disable Camera

Comment: @moonboots Hi, I am aware of the cycles panel but I want to achieve it in eevee as it's much faster

Answer (score 0):

In Eevee by default only the lights and the world will be reflected, the objects won't, if you want them to be reflected you need to use a *Light Probe > Reflection Cubemap* [as explained here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee), if you don't want the object to be seen by the camera, once you've baked the indirect lighting, just hide the object for render, its reflection will still be visible.